# How do I install a specific version of an IDEA plugin?

Tags: java, ide, plugins, intellij-idea

I have experienced problems since moving to the latest version of one of the IDEA plugins I use. I can download ZIP files of previous versions of the plugin from their website but I can't find any installation instructions for how to *manually install a specific version* of a plugin.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Think you can simple drop the jar in the plugins directory:

> `idea.plugins.path=${user.home}/.IntelliJIdea80/config/plugins`

On Windows:

> `idea.plugins.path=%USERPROFILE%\.IntelliJIdea80\config\plugins`

Comment: What is odd is that I cannot find the *current* version (which I have installed and am using) anywhere under either this directory or my %IDEA_HOME% directory!

Answer (score 34):

You could also download the zip and then in **Settings Plugins** press **install plugin from disk** and choose the **zipfile**. 
Works like a charm on my Mac =)

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA -> Preferences -> Plugins -> install plugin from disk

Comment: You don't need to download it as zipped. You can just zip it too. Thanks for the answer :-)

Comment: Anyone know if intellij supports this now in 2020? This product isn't free (unless you using community) and this is a useful feature when a plugin author breaks the plugin.

Comment: FYI, trying to download using the .zip link from github, then install from disk gave me: "Error: Failed to load plugin descriptor from file..."

Answer (score 12):

If you are on Mac, it would be:

```
~/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdeaXX
```

where XX is IDEA version number code.

You can [find more details](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) for different platforms in the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux I found the "Pydantic" PyCharm plugin's `.jar` files installed in: `~/.local/share/JetBrains/PyCharm2024.1/Pydantic/lib`.

I was able to downgrade the plugin by:

1. going to the plugins GitHub page
2. downloading a zip of a previous release
3. removing the existing jar files from above folder
4. adding the jar files from downloaded zip into the above folder
5. restarting my JetBrains IDE (PyCharm)

This process should work for all JetBrains IDEs.