# How to install a specific version of JRebel plugin in Intellijidea

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, ide

I want to install a previous version of Jrebel plugin into the Intellij, in the Intellij plugin store, the latest JRebel version is 6.1.x but i need to install 5.6.0. I tried downloading "**jrebel-5.6.0-nosetup.zip**"
 and installing it by option "Install plugin from disk", but shown me the error as in below screenshot:-

[image]

Secondly, i tried to install the latest JRebel from repository and after that changing the **Jrebel.jar** path from plugin settings but that also shows me the error while activating it from server as "**License server 3 or newer required**."

I've this 5.6.0 JRebel working in eclipse also activated from my license server.

Isn't there any way to directly download and install any specific version of plugin. I also followed few stack overflow questions for the same, but they even didn;t have specific answer. 
One of those is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226066/how-do-i-install-a-specific-version-of-an-idea-plugin?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

You have downloaded the binary distribution of JRebel, which is not an IDE plugin.

You can download the exact version of JRebel plugin for IntelliJ IDEA from the [plugins portal](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4441?pr=idea&showAllUpdates=true) and install from disk (the same way as you have tried with "nosetup" ZIP.

Alternatively, you can also do the following:

1. Install latest JRebel plugin from plugins repository Unzip
2. jrebel-5.6.0-nosetup.zip to file system In
3. Settings->JRebel->Advanced, specify custom jrebel.jar location

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Anton I tried the ways you just mentioned, and they are helpful, i was able to install the Jrebel-5.6.0 quickly, but now it seems there is something wrong with license server, it's still giving the same error **License server 3 or newer required.**.

Comment: @Abhishek-M it means exactly that - you have to upgrade the license server. Please consult JRebel support for help.

Comment: @AntonArhipov consider accepting this as the best answer.